# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare format_currency() (previously declared in

Tags: php

```
$currency_prefix = "Rp. ";

$currency_postfix = ",-";

function format_currency($v){

    global $currency_prefix,$currency_postfix;

    return $currency_prefix.number_format($v,0,"",".").$currency_postfix;
}
```

can help ? erron in italic

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare format_currency() (previously declared
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\ba\web_config_vars.php:12) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ba\web_config_vars.php on line 15

```
function is_active($v){

    global $_SERVER;

    $filename=substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],"/")+1);

    if ($v==$filename) return ' class="aktif" ';

}

?>
```

Comment: What is on line 12?

Comment: You've declared twice the function. Once line 12, once line 15

Comment: Maybe your file "web_config_vars.php" contains another declaration of `format_currency()`?

Comment: this line 12 and 15

Comment: function format_duit($v){
    global $currency_prefix,$currency_postfix;
   return $currency_prefix.number_format($v,0,"",".").$currency_postfix;
}

Comment: can you post web_config_vars.php full code? for better understanding

Comment: web_config_vars.php is a database

Comment: <?php
'echo<div id="login">';
// *** CONFIGURATION VARS
$web_title  = "Web Online Shop V3 Demo";
$db_host    = "localhost";
$db_user    = "root";
$db_pass    = "";
$db_name    = "toko_online";

$currency_prefix = "Rp. ";
$currency_postfix = ",-";
function format_duit($v){
    global $currency_prefix,$currency_postfix;
   return $currency_prefix.number_format($v,0,"",".").$currency_postfix;
}

function is_active($v){
    global $_SERVER;
 $filename=substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],"/")+1);
    if ($v==$filename) return ' class="aktif" ';
}
?>

Comment: This is unreadable in comment. You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59836614/edit) your question